# How can I get the CallSid for an outgoing rest call?

Tags: php, twilio

I'm using Twilio's rest lib in PHP and making an outgoing call. Can I get the callsid right away i.e.:

```
$callout = $twilioclient->account->calls->create($client, $phone, $callurl, array("Method"=>"GET"));
$newcallsid=$callout->callsid;
```

It doesn't seem to be working but, I'm probably doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `callsid` to `sid`

```
echo $callout->sid;
```

You should be able to see all of the properties of the object by echoing it

```
echo $callout
```